# Missing Hive Processors In Nifi 1.19.1

Tags: hive, hiveql, apache-nifi, apache-nifi-toolkit

I downloaded the latest Nifi version. i was able to connect nifi to an oracle database and it works fine. However, i need to connect nifi to hive, my problem is i cant find any processors related to hive. There is no SelectHiveQL processor and no PutHiveQL processor or any processor related to hive at all. not even the controller services for hive is found.

[image]

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong? I just need to connect Nifi to hive and i can't find the processors responsible for this.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check a [Developer Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#build)

> Apache Hive 1.1 Bundle `include-hive1_1` Adds support for Apache Hive 1.1.X

> Apache Hive 3 Bundle `include-hive3` Adds support for Apache Hive 3.X

> The following command is used to generate a standard binary distribution of Apache NiFi: `mvn clean install -Pinclude-grpc,contrib-check`

You should build NiFi:
`mvn clean install -Pinclude-hive3,include-hive1_1`

Comment: well I get a warning, first i use "mvn archetype:generate", filter on nifi , then select "Select org.apache.nifi:nifi-processor-bundle-archetype project", after the archetype project is created I run the command you gave me "mvn clean install -Pinclude-hive3,include-hive1_1" but i get this warning ////////////[WARNING] The requested profile "include-hive3" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[WARNING] The requested profile "include-hive1_1" could not be activated because it does not exist.

Comment: @speroo check this profile: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/main/nifi-assembly/pom.xml#L1092

Comment: @speroo did you check this?